# Call method with parameters from string in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

i have an MVC3 application and a notification system in my database.
This notification system, save many things such: userid, text, status and a pending_action.
This last column has a value like "http://localhost:3713/Controller/Action?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3" or "/Controller/Action?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3" that is the action to perform after the user that receives the notification, perform accept.
The problem is that i don't know how can i perform that method from the string i have.
I did a Redirect(NotificationObject.PendingAction) but it didn't work.

I don't know if this is the best way to save the pending_action in the database, if there is a better method, then better :)

I hope you can help me :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Redirect("/Home/Action?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3");
    }

    public ActionResult Action(string param1, string param2, string param3)
    {
        var data = string.Format(
            "param1={0}, param1={1}, param1={2}", 
            param1, 
            param2, 
            param3
        );
        return Content(data, "text/plain");
    }
}
```

Also don't you think that it would be better if you made your database a little more ASP.NET MVC agnostic and stored only `param1=1`, `param2=2` and `param3=3` values in some table and then have your MVC application construct the proper url based on its routing configuration?

Comment: That works, but only if the Action method redirects to a view.. but i need to continue with the execution of your Index method (in your example).

Comment: @Phoenix_uy, I don't understand you.

Comment: @Phoenix_uy, can't you perform whatever you have to perform before returning?

Comment: I cant... the method i need is this:
public ActionResult Index(){
   //CALL PENDING_METHOD
   //UPDATE NOTIFICATION STATUS FROM PENDING TO COMPLETE OR SOMETHING..
   return ActionX

Comment: @Phoenix_uy, I am loosing you :-)